# react bootstrap dropdown on firefox

Tags: firefox, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using React Bootstrap Dropdown that will render text depending on what DropDown selection you choose. However, it only works on browsers that isn't Firefox.

```
<MenuItem key={item.key} onSelect={this.handleFilterSelect.bind(this)} eventKey={item.key} className="filter-option text-right">
{item.label}
</MenuItem>
```

I've tried switching onSelect with onClick, but I still get the same error. In the Firefox consol, the error says,

```
"ReferenceError: event is not defined react-bundle-1e7c66351cc2cc9138d2f506e79409f1.js:27:31664"
```

Any have an idea what's going on?

Comment: It's hard to know without seeing the un-minified source where the error is. Did you make sure that the issue lies in the above code by removing it and seeing if you still have the error? Can you disable minify/uglify/compression from your build process and post the code around the error?

Comment: I'm seeing this error as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling React events "the React way": supply the event vs. supply the result to a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42864637/handling-react-events-the-react-way-supply-the-event-vs-supply-the-result-to)